# Find Row In DataTable that's been transposed

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable thats been transposed on a date column and now looks like this

```
+--------+------------+-------------+
|        | 1/1/2015   |  1/2/2015   |
+--------+-------+------------------+
| FieldA | Type       | MySQL       |
| FieldB | Header     | Spreads     |
| FieldC | Auto Align | On          |
+---+------------+------------------+
```

What I want to be able to do is get to a specific value based on the column and row names.
So for example if I know I want FieldA with date 1/1/2015 I should get back Type

Code used to transpose DataTable

```
 public static DataTable Transpose(DataTable dt)
        {
            DataTable dtNew = new DataTable();

            //adding columns    
            for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                dtNew.Columns.Add(i.ToString());
            }



            //Changing Column Captions: 
            dtNew.Columns[0].ColumnName = " ";

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //For dateTime columns use like below
                dtNew.Columns[i + 1].ColumnName = Convert.ToDateTime(dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                //Else just assign the ItermArry[0] to the columnName prooperty
            }

            //Adding Row Data
            for (int k = 1; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                DataRow r = dtNew.NewRow();
                r[0] = dt.Columns[k].ToString();
                for (int j = 1; j <= dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                    r[j] = dt.Rows[j - 1][k];
                dtNew.Rows.Add(r);
            }

            return dtNew;
        }
```

Comment: Is this datable data being returned from a Pivot Query..? show the query that you use to generate the rows / columns

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the transposed `DataTable` normally.

```
var monthCol = "01/01/2015"; // based on format in your code
var fieldName = "FieldA";
var res = dtTransposed.Select($"[ ] = {fieldName}")[0][monthCol]; // you really should name the first column, say "Field"
```

If you know the datatype of the data, you could use `Field<>(monthCol)` instead.

You can also use LINQ:

```
var res = dtTransposed.AsEnumerable().Where(dr => dr[" "] == fieldName).Select(dr => dr[monthCol]);
```